# React Setstate makes my state item undefined after JSONizing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, state

I'm trying to make a workout log for myself and as a training for React and Node.js. I've got my own API with many functions, including one called "/get-workouts", which is, as the name says, to get workouts from the database.

Here's the API

```
app.get('/get-workouts', (req, res) => {
db('workoutlogger').select('*')
.limit(3)
.from('workouts')
.then(workouts => {
    if(workouts.length) {
        console.log(workouts);
        res.status(200).json(workouts);
    } else {
        res.status(400).send('No workouts found');
    }
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(404).send('Error getting workouts')
   })
})
```

Here's my frontend :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        workoutList: {}
    }
}

getWorkouts = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/get-workouts')
    .then(workouts => {
        workouts.json();
    })
    .then(workoutList => {
        this.setState({workoutList})
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('There was an error getting workouts', err))
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getWorkouts();
}
```

If I console.log "workouts" in the first .then() of my fetch. My API clearly logs the list of the last 3 workouts I logged in, and initially, this.state.workoutList is an object. But once set.state supposedly set the workoutList to be a list of my workouts, it logs as undefined, and I can't display it. Where does the problem come from ?

Comment: You should be returning something so the next `then()'s` can use them. In your case, return `workouts.json()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass values between consecutive `.then`s, they aren't implicitly passed. The return value of one `.then` becomes the argument of the next. So do this:

```
.then(workouts => workouts.json())
.then(workoutList => {
    this.setState({workoutList})
})
```

Removing the curly braces means it implicity returns `workouts.json()`, which will then becomes the `workoutList` argument in the next `.then`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! So basically it's either your solution, or else I should have added "return" before my "workouts.json()" ?

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function needs to be understood correctly here.

Arrow function without curly braces implicitly returns whatever the next statement evaluates to. However, if you use curly braces, you are forming a block which is nothing but a list of statements (which evaluate to `undefined`). Thus we need to use `return` explicitly in that case.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        workoutList: {}
    }
}

getWorkouts = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/get-workouts')
    .then(workouts => {
        return workouts.json();
    })
    // above then fn can also be written (without curly braces) as below:
    // .then(workouts => workouts.json()) -- removing curly braces returns result of statement implicitly
    .then(workoutList => {
        this.setState({workoutList})
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('There was an error getting workouts', err))
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getWorkouts();
}
```